# How to convert this SAS date value in milliseconds

Tags: date, datetime, sas

I'm able to convert a date in this format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" in milliseconds because I found an interesting question in that site.

However I can't use it to do my goal. This is my dataset:

```
%let first="05/23/2016 12:00:00 AM";
%let second=%sysfunc(intck(sec,%sysfunc(dhms('01jan1970'd,0,0,0)),%sysfunc(dhms('01jan1960'd,1,0,0))));
    data _null_;
        if "&first." ne ""
        then data_input=input("&first.",YYMMDD10.);
        else data_input=today();
        final=(dhms(data_input,0,0,0)+&second)*1000;
        CALL SYMPUT('final',final);
    run;
%PUT "Final:&final.";
```

This is the output:

```
Final:       .
```

Why?

I try to do this:

```
then data_input=input("05/23/2016 12:00:00 AM",mdyampm.);
```

In that case I receive an error message:

```
FATAL: DATA STEP compilation stopped due to syntax errors.
```

How can I fixed it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this.  `input` will get you what you want.

```
%let first="05/23/2016 12:00:00 AM";

data _null_;
  data_input = input(&first.,mdyampm23.);
  put data_input= datetime17.;
  data_milliseconds = data_input*1000;
run;
```

`input` gets you to datetime in seconds, then multiply by 1000.

If you then need to adjust to the 1970 epoch instead of the 1960 epoch, you do something like

```
%let first="05/23/2016 12:00:00 AM";
%let second=('01JAN1970:00:00:00'dt-'01JAN1960:00:00:00'dt);
data _null_;
  data_input = input(&first.,mdyampm23.) + &second.;
  put data_input= datetime17.;
  data_milliseconds = data_input*1000;
run;
```

Or the reverse (1960 minus 1970), depending on what you're actually doing (converting SAS dt's to Unix or Unix to SAS).

Comment: Thanks it work! I made a little edit because with your solution is useless second variable. Thanks